# Why do carriage returns in Excel not visually show up in Notepad when you save the Excel as a Text Tab Delimited?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad

If you put a carriage return in a cell of Excel (by pressing Alt + Enter), and save your file as a Text (Tab delimited).txt file, the carriage return does not appear when you open the file in Notepad.

```
This
is
a
carriage
return
```

becomes

```
"Thisisacarriagereturn"
```

in Notepad.

Why? How is the carriage return being encoded in the text file?

Comment: I believe Notepad needs a carriage return and a line feed. I also think Wordpad does not. Does text file look correct in WordPad?

Answer (score 3):

Typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a cell results in a `Line Feed` (`LF`, ASCII code 10) character, and as such it is also saved to the file.

Here's a copy of your test text in a `xls` file looked at with a hex editor (0A is hex representation of decimal 10):

```
00 00 00 19 00 00 54 68 69 73 0A 69 73 0A 61 0A
63 61 72 72 69 61 67 65 0A 72 65 74 75 72 6E FF
```

Windows Notepad requires a `Carriage Return` + `Line Feed`, ASCII codes 13 + 10, to recognize it as a new line

Notepad++ (a freeware text editor) has the ability to recognise any of `LF`, `CR` or `CR+LF` as a new line.

Here's your test copied from Notepad++.

`"This
is
a
carriage
return"`